# How to actually create an event in C#

Tags: c#, events, initialization

I am  a beginner in C# events , and delegates.  Few questions that would make sense if you look at [the URL I have used to learn about events](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11541/The-Simplest-C-Events-Example-Imaginable).

1. Can I ever have an event without a delegate associated to it?  The exmaples that I have found always have them together.
2. For example I do not understand how does the event get generated. I am totally lost, I understand that Tick is defined as an event but what is the Tick's event description? where do I define what constitutes the Tick?
3. Also where does the Tick value gets ever initailized.  It seems that all the examples I have looked at never initialize the event and have a similar statement to statement : If (Tick ! =null) in the attached example but it is not obviuos where is the Tick is initialized.  I have looked around and I just cant find any answer.
   Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: @Tim: I was wondering did you took away my URL?

Comment: Take a look here http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_delegates_and_events.html

Comment: @user1298925: No. He just formatted your question properly.

Comment: @user1298925 - the URL is still there. I made it a link, as that's the preferred style.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth : Oops , I see it now , I added my URL again .

Comment: And I took it away again :)

Comment: @user1298925: No need to add the URL again. It was never gone. The text "the URL I have used to learn about events." links to the URL.

Comment: @Tim: How do you make it a link? Curious for next time. Thanks

Comment: @Tim; never mind, I found out

Comment: @user1298925: Just click on edit on your question and have a look at the text it now contains. Furthermore, simply read the provided help when composing a question!

Comment: There's an orange question mark that will show some help for more advanced things, including linking you to http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help which is a good resource to learn.

Comment: @Tim,   and Daniel Hilgarth  Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. No, events are just a special use of delegates. You can't have an event without a delegate (though you can have a delegate without an event - read up on [delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/900fyy8e.aspx) for more info).
2. Not really sure I understand your question here. The description of the event would be in the documentation. Looking at the code alone, you just know that there is an event called Tick on that object that you can attach an event handler to.
3. When you add an event handler to Tick (that's the `+=` lines you see) it will become non-null. That's what those `!= null` checks are doing - making sure that *someone* has attached onto the event.

Answer (score 2):

An event is simply a combination of an add method and a remove method, both of which take a single parameter of the same delegate type.  What the event does with a passed-in delegate is entirely up to the implementation.

The most common thing to do with an event delegate received in the `Add` handler is to `Delegate.Combine` it with the previously-added delegates (if any), but there are some other possibilities as well:

If an object will support many kinds of events, but many instances will have zero subscribers for most of them, one could add the delegate to a table.  Many WinForms events do this.

If one wants to allow subscribers to use contravariant delegate types, one could place received delegates into an array, `List<>`, linked list, of delegates or delegate-holding objects.

If the event represents something that some types of objects would fire, but a particular instance never will, the event may simply discard the delegate.  Consider, for example, an abstract `ObservableFoo` class with an abstract change-notification event, and a contract that says any time the instance's properties change it will invoke all passed-in delegates will be invoked; an `ImmutableFoo` class derived from it could accept subscription requests, but since it would never change, it would never have to invoke the passed-in delegates (or do anything else with them) and could simply discard them.

Since an event is a pair of methods which take a delegate type as a parameter, every event must "by definition" use delegates as its parameter type.  All *non-trivial* events must store passed-in delegates in some form.  The most common way to accept multiple subscriptions is to combine them into a multicast delegate (I dislike the design, btw, but it is the most common); other approaches may be employed, but an event which is going to use passed-in delegates must store them somehow.

BTW, there are two ways to declare an event in C#: one may supply the add/remove handlers explicitly, in which case the compiler will create a event with those handlers.  One may also supply just the event name and delegate type, in which case the compiler will create an event with the specified name and scope, a private variable *with the same name* and appropriate delegate type, and thread-safe add/remove methods which add or remove the event from the indicated variable.  Statements of the form `eventName += something;` or `eventName -= something;` will be processed as calls to the "add" or "remove" methods; all other uses of the name will refer to the delegate.  Note that in old versions of C#, use of `eventName += something;` and `eventName -= something;` within a class would be processed using the `+=` and `-=` operations on the delegate which were not thread-safe, but newer versions have changed that behavior.